# How to format the input of EditText when typing with thousands separators (,) in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, number-formatting, textwatcher

I've an `edittext` , it only gets numeric without decimal numbers.

```
android:inputType="number"
```

I want to separate thousands while I'm typing . For example 25,000 .

I know I should use `TextWatcher` and I've used this code but I couldn't make it work :

```
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable viewss) {
            String s = null;
            try {
                // The comma in the format specifier does the trick
                s = String.format("%,d", Long.parseLong(viewss.toString()));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }

        }
```

Could you help me to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

add this into your app's Gradle 
compile 'com.aldoapps:autoformatedittext:0.9.3'
in XML
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

```
<com.aldoapps.autoformatedittext.AutoFormatEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:isDecimal="true"
    android:maxLength="8"
    android:id="@+id/number"/>
```

This lib automatically add (,) (.)

Answer (score 1):

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
String yourFormattedString = formatter.format(100000);
```

Use DecimalFormat

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version of [Adrian Cid Almageur's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28758064/8848409)

```
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.widget.EditText
import java.text.DecimalFormat
import java.text.ParseException

class NumberTextWatcher(private val editText: EditText) : TextWatcher {

    private val decimalFormat = DecimalFormat("#,###.##")
    private val decimalFormatNoFrac = DecimalFormat("#,###")

    private var hasFractionalPart = false

    init {
        decimalFormat.isDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown = true
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this)

        try {
            val initialLength = editText.text.length

            val v = s.toString()
                .replace(decimalFormat.decimalFormatSymbols.groupingSeparator.toString(), "")
            val number = decimalFormat.parse(v)

            val cp = editText.selectionStart
            if (hasFractionalPart) {
                editText.setText(decimalFormat.format(number))
            } else {
                editText.setText(decimalFormatNoFrac.format(number))
            }
            val endLength = editText.length()
            val selection = (cp + (endLength - initialLength))
            if (selection > 0 && selection <= editText.text.length) {
                editText.setSelection(selection)
            } else {
                editText.setSelection(editText.text.length - 1)
            }
        } catch (nfe: NumberFormatException) {

        } catch (ex: ParseException) {

        }

        editText.addTextChangedListener(this)
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        hasFractionalPart =
            s.toString().contains(decimalFormat.decimalFormatSymbols.decimalSeparator)
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
android:inputType="number"
android:maxLines="1"
```

```
import android.icu.text.NumberFormat
import java.util.Locale

val editText = activityMainBinding.editText
var oldNumber = -1
var isRestart = false
editText.addTextChangedListener {
    //starts again when using "editText.setText()"
    if (isRestart) {
        isRestart = false
        return@addTextChangedListener
    }
    if (it.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        oldNumber = -1
        return@addTextChangedListener
    }

    //user writes 1 000 and user removed 1 and "toInt()" return 0
    //user writes 00 and "toInt()" return 0
    //user writes 05 and "toInt()" return 5
    val currentNumber = it.toString().replace(" ", "").toInt()

    //user writes 10 000 000 but will see 1 000 000, will see the previous number
    if (currentNumber > 1_000_0000) {
        val currentSelection = editText.selectionStart - 1
        val formatMoney = formatToMoney(oldNumber)
        isRestart = true
        editText.setText(formatMoney)
        editText.setSelection(currentSelection)
        return@addTextChangedListener
    }
    val currentSelection = editText.selectionStart

    //user writes 10 000 and user removed space and we delete 0 and user will see 1 000
    val newNumber =
        if (it[0] != '0' && currentNumber == oldNumber) {
            currentNumber.toString()
                .removeRange(currentSelection - 1, currentSelection)
                .toInt()
        } else currentNumber

    if (newNumber == 0) {
        oldNumber = -1
        isRestart = true
        editText.setText("0")
        editText.setSelection(1)
        return@addTextChangedListener
    }
    val formatMoney = formatToMoney(newNumber)

    //move selection one step forward or backward
    //when added a space -> step forward
    //when removed a space -> step backward
    val incOrDecSelection = formatMoney.length - it.length
    var newSelection = currentSelection + incOrDecSelection
 
    //user writes 1 000 and user remove 1 and "newSelection" will -1
    if (newSelection < 0) {
        newSelection = 0
    }
    oldNumber = newNumber
    isRestart = true
    editText.setText(formatMoney)
    editText.setSelection(newSelection)
}

//Need to use "Locale.US" different countries use different delimiters "," or "."
fun formatToMoney(number: Int): String {
    val formatMoney = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(number)
    return formatMoney.replace(",", " ")
}
```

We get the result
1 000
10 000
100 000
1 000 000

[NumberFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/NumberFormat)
[DecimalFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/DecimalFormat)
[Locale](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale)

I wrote comments in the code.
Remember that [Int limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/integer-limits?view=msvc-170).
You can wrap the code `try catch` and send exception to the server, maybe i missed something.