# how should I add a TextChangedListener to an EditText component?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android programming. I encountered a problem and I'm having a hard time applying the solution given in this topic:
[How to format the input of EditText when typing with thousands separators (,) in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757931/how-to-format-the-input-of-edittext-when-typing-with-thousands-separators-in)

so far I have made a seperate Java file and pasted the main code in it but I can't find out how to "add editText.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcher(editText)); to my EditText component".
my XML EditText looks like this:

```
        <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define the EditText variable as an instance variable in your class

```
private EditText mEditText;
```

Then in some place such as onCreate or onViewCreated you can initialize your EditText and add the listener.

```
mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // Get changed text s here and use it 
    } 

});
```

Answer (score 20):

You can also use [Butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) for this

```
@OnTextChanged(value = R.id.etName, callback = OnTextChanged.Callback.AFTER_TEXT_CHANGED)
public void nameChanged(CharSequence text) {
    //do stuff
}
```

UPDATE: Kotlin Extension

```
fun EditText.afterTextChanged(onAfterChangeText: (String) -> Unit) {
    this.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
            onAfterChangeText(editable.toString())
        }
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
editText.afterTextChanged {
//do stuff
}
```

Kotlin without Extension:

```
editText.doAfterTextChanged {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to find the EditText element in your Activity or Fragment like:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Then you should be able to do

```
editText.addTextChangedListener()
```

I recommend you take a look at butterknife library, http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/. It makes your code more organized if you have a lot of listeners.

You can simply do

```
@OnTextChanged(R.id.editText)
public void listener() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Activity, get editText reference:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With ButterKnife

```
@OnTextChanged(value = { R.id.firstNameEditText, R.id.lastNameEditText },
    callback = OnTextChanged.Callback.AFTER_TEXT_CHANGED)
void inputName(EditText editText, Editable editable) {
// Greet user...
}
```

P.S.

http://craftedcourses.io/all-about-butter-knife-part-1/